# How is this question opinion based

Tags: discussion

[Is any philosopher in particular associated with there being no conception of change without one of stasis, and vice versa?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68197/is-any-philosopher-in-particular-associated-with-there-being-no-conception-of-ch)

Is the answer just "no-one"?

Comment: Is there really any philosophical content there?

Comment: there's a religious / buddhist context, for sure @D.Halsey should i add it?

Comment: Negation is a hugely neglected topic of logic in the West, but theories like (yes, that same obsessive topic) Intuitionism, or at the other end of sense Meinong, point out that our way of handling it is deeply flawed, especially when talking about definitions and change.  There is a *lot* of philosophical content here.  But I do think the question body needs help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with the following comment:

"This edit does not look particularly opinion based [sic]...– Conifold Nov 7 at 19:59"

It's been my experience that some who vote to close are the same who frequently find their own questions closed, particularly regarding the question of what constitutes opinion as used as criterion offered by the site. As far as I can tell, there are those whose reputations accurately reflect a serious cogency and demonstration of scholarship, and others who through marginal contributions accrue points scattershot. (And yes, I'm in the latter category!)